# Stochastic Integral martingale if no $dt$ term?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals

There is a proposition in my book that

For a process $M_t$ to be a martingale, it is necessary that its stochastic differential $dM_t$ has no $dt$ term.

Why is this exactly? My *guess* is that it implies there is no change with respect to time $t$. This is speculation, and is the story told with the 2nd property given regarding conditional expectation.

A martingale only requires that:
$$1. \space \forall t, E \|M_t \| < \infty$$ and
$$2. \space \forall t,s>0, \space E[M_{t+s}|\mathcal{F}_t] = M_t$$

Comment: What class of processes are you talking about? Is $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ an Itô process, a semimartingale,...?

Comment: The context is not entirely clear, but I believe it is an Ito process.

Although, the properties $1.$ and $2.$ that I listed are in reference to martingales of brownian motion, so perhaps those are irrelevant here.

Comment: In this case, see this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1035461/

Comment: Also related to : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984173/proof-that-the-drift-term-of-a-martingale-vanishes