# Justification for why an Itô process is a martingale if and only if the drift is identically zero?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

I am self-studying stochastic calculus in the context of mathematical finance, and the following is stated in my text without justification:

> An *Itô process* is a random process $X(t)$ whose differential can be
> expressed as $$dX(t) = \xi\left(t, X(t)\right)dt + \sigma\left(t, X(t)\right)dZ(t).$$
>
> A *martingale* is a process $X(t)$ for which $\textbf{E}[X(t + s) | X(t)] = X(t).$
>
> *An Itô process is a martingale if and only if the
> coefficient of dt, the drift, is identically zero.*

Is there a proof of the above that one with only a background in elementary probability and measure theory and knowledge of the above definitions could understand?

This may appear to be a duplicate of the following:
[show that the solution is a local martingale iff it has zero drift](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035461/show-that-the-solution-is-a-local-martingale-iff-it-has-zero-drift%20/)

The above solution seems to require a more advanced understanding of stochastic processes. Is there a less rigorous, more general reasoning that I could use to convince myself?

Comment: It would help if you explain what you don't understand about the proof. Do you know how prove the easier direction (i.e. that if the drift vanishes, then $X$ is a martingale)? One more remark: the definition of a martingale in your source is not very precise. Usually the continuous-time definition is with regards to a particular filtration. I think in the context of a single diffusion process $X$, the filtration can be understood to be the natural filtration of $X$, but this is rarely sufficiently general.

Comment: the statement is not true:
in general $X$ is only a local martingale if the drift is equal to zero. 
In order to get martingales you need some assumptions for $\sigma$.