# Semimartingale Decomposition of Ornstein Uhlenbeck Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

I'm looking for a quick sanity check for something that is confusing me. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semimartingale#Continuous_semimartingales) if $X_t$ is an Ito process that can be written as a stochastic integral + a time integral then the term of finite variation in the decomposition $X_t = M_t + A_t$ is the time integral, and the martingale part $M_t$ is the stochastic integral.

If $X_t$ is a Ornstein Uhlenbeck process then it has a closed form $X_t = \int_0^t\sigma e^{-\theta(t-s)}dB_s$, and following this logic $A_t = 0$ and $X_t$ decomposes as a purely a martingale, but this is not possible if $X_t$ satisfies the SDE

$$dX_t = -aX_tdt + \sigma dB_t$$

Since solutions of an SDE are only martingales if they have no drift ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060102/justification-for-why-an-it%C3%B4-process-is-a-martingale-if-and-only-if-the-drift-is)). What is the mistake I'm making to get this supposed contradiction?

Comment: The stochastic integral $\int_0^t\sigma e^{-\theta(t-s)}dB_s$ is not a martingale — the integrand depends on $t$!

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Is there a way to find out what the decomposition of $X_t$ would be in terms of a martingale and finite variation part? Or is it hopeless for a closed form.

Comment: You can rewrite $X_t = e^{-\theta t} \int_0^t \sigma e^{\theta s}dB_s$ and now apply Ito's product rule to the right hand side to get a closed form.

Comment: You get your decomposition immediately by integrating the SDE.