# What proves that a random process with zero diffusion is not a martingale?

Tags: brownian-motion, martingales

Consider the process $dX_t=W_t dt+0 dW_t$, alternatively $X_t=\int_0^t W_s ds$.  $W_t$ is Brownian motion.  I read a proof that $X_t$ is a martingale that simply states "Because the diffusion of $dX_t$ is 0, $X_t$ is not a martingale."

By [definition](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT15_070JF13_Lec9.pdf), a stochastic process $X_t$ adapted to a filtration $\{F_t\}$ is a martingale iff 
$$
E(|X_t|) <\infty, t \geq 0 \tag{1}
$$
and
$$E(X_t|{\cal F}_s)=X_s, 0\leq s<t \tag{2}$$

*Question:* What exactly about conditions (1) and (2) establishes that if a random process has 0 diffusion, it is not a martingale?

I am asking because I see the 0-diffusion condition used often for this purpose, but in the above example, of a process which is still random even though it has a zero diffusion, I don't get it.

Comment: Full answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1035461/).

Comment: A constant process has no diffusion term, but is also a martingale.

Comment: Thanks Did for showing the question was asked before.  What do you think of Theoretical Economist's counterexample?

Comment: Also Did, not to pick nits, but not all martingales are local martingales, the other question you referenced is particular to [local martingales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_martingale).