# Finding the drift coefficient

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-differential-equations

$X_t$ is a solution of SDL

$$dX_t=b(X_t)dt+X_tdB_t.$$

What is the the drift coefficient $b(x)$ of this equation, if the square of its solution

$$M_t=X^2_t, t\geq0,$$

is a martingale?

So far, I managed to apply Ito formula to function $f(x)=x^2$ and got that

$$dX^2_t=2b(X_t)X_tdt+X^2_tdt+2X_t^2dB_t.$$

The answer for the exercise is $b(x)=-\frac{x}{2}$. In other words, as I understand it, we want to remove the regular part of the equation above to get

$$dX^2_t=2X_t^2dB_t.$$

Why?

Comment: For $M$ to be a (local) martingale you want the drift term $2b(X_t)X_t\,dt + X^2_t\,dt$ to vanish. For this you need $2b(x)x+x^2=0$.

Comment: Your suggestion gave me an idea that the proposition about $\int_0^tH_sdB_s$ for $H\in H^2[0,T]$ being a martingale can be applied here.

Comment: @TheGrandDuke Yes, that's a good idea. Take also a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1035461/36150)